# How can I make ActiveStorage work within my locales?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, rails-activestorage

**How can I make Activestorage work within my locales like** `www.localhost:3000/es/` ?

I had activestorage up and running. The images were saved and viewable in the views.

Then, I added my locales to my routes with this code:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

    resources :posts
    root to: 'pages#index'

get '/*locale/*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
get '/*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), constraints: lambda { |req| I18n.available_locales.none? { |locale| req.path.starts_with? locale.to_s } }
```

I also have a before action in my `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
end

def self.default_url_options(options = {})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

**If I remove the code above, then the images are displayed. How can I make the image_tags work with my internationalization?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my routes. I added a LocaleConstraint. 
Here are routes that work with ActiveStorage:

```
class LocaleConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    (I18n.available_locales.none? { |locale| request.path.starts_with? locale.to_s }) && (!request.path.include? 'rails/active_storage/blobs')
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

    devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }

    resources :posts

    get '/*locale/*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
    get '/*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), constraints: LocaleConstraint

  end

end
```